# VPN connection not accessible on network

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I am trying to share VPN connection with LAN and WLAN. Connected in terminal with nordvpn app, set up static DHCP IP on both LAN and WLAN, using phone as USB internet tethering.

Everything works when sharing usb0 connection(as only internet connection, not with VPN) to eth0 and wlan0. However, when using nordvpn connect in terminal, for a short period internet connection on devices is ok, but then internet is not accessible on other device, but on main computer with VPN it works. Only by disconnecting nordvpn and reconnecting and reapplying the commands it works, again for a short period. This is how my tun0 looks like, with the inet IP changing with every connect:`inet 10.8.3.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.3.2`, then using the commands sharing VPN connection:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I suspect it has something to do with the route table because when adding default tun0 ip address it works again, but only for a while then tun0 IP inet is changing and have to do all over again. This is the route table (ip of tun0 is not always the same):

```
default         10.8.0.8        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 usb0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     205    0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 usb0
```

With iptables -S :

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

At the end it shows like `usb0 -j DROP, wlan0 -j DROP and eth0 -j DROP`  when disconnecting with vpn in terminal (that does not happen when usb0 connection is being used, even when the phone is not plugged in). On tun0 if it does not exist, above iptables are not working and only by reapplying them they work, but again for a short period. If understood correctly, it has something to do with the inet IP of tun0 changing but how to make it static so that there is no need to reapply everything, don't know. I am a beginner in all of this and appreciate any help. Hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Edit: After couple of days, I found out that adding `route add default gw (tun0)`  is at least giving me a few hours, maybe half a day and then internet connectivity stops even on the main computer. Nordvpn shows connected, but there is no internet. The reason why immediately didn't work when adding default tun0 as route was because it needs to be tun0 gateway and not the ip assigned to the main computer (gateway usually has ending with 1).  Another approach was to add `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT` without adding default route. It would not provoke vpn reconnect and ip change, but time is still very short, shorter than route default tun0.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days trying to make it work, I switched to openvpn app in terminal and it works without problems. This would be technically a workaround and not a real solution for the nordvpn app itself. Commands for forwarding in iptables is ok and there is no DROP appearing even after restart or turning of vpn connection, so there is also no need with route table config. Reading on other questions regarding vpn, it seems this is a "bug" inside nordvpn app, perhaps the provider intended it so, don't know. I recommend openvpn to solve such issues.